# VueJS with bootsrap carousel how to pass images to the carousel

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4

My requirement is something like this.

1. I got the list of images from the back-end.
2. I want to pass those image names to the **carousel** to display images.

This is my code.

```
<template>
  <div class="">
    <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="carousel-item active" v-for="banner in banners">
      <img :src="`./assets/${banner}`" alt=""  class="img-fluid"   >

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      banners:["logo.png","index.png","Capture.png"]
    }
  },
  methods:{

  }
}
</script>
```

But this method doesn't work. How do I pass images to my **carousel** element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting all carousel slides to `active`, so they will all display at once. Use `:class` to conditionally set the active slide...

```
<div class="carousel-item" v-for="(banner,idx) in banners" :class="{ active: idx==0 }">
      <img :src="banner" alt="" class="img-fluid">
</div>
```

Also, make sure the `:src="'./assets/${banner}'"` reference is actually working to find the images.

[Working demo on Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/uWzrWhTvYm)

Note: You ***don't*** want to use jQuery `$('.carousel').carousel();` to load the Carousel since you're already using the `data-ride="carousel"` attribute. As stated  [in the Bootstrap 4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#via-data-attributes)...

> The data-ride="carousel" attribute is used to mark a carousel as
>   animating starting at page load. It cannot be used in combination with
>   (redundant and unnecessary) explicit JavaScript initialization of the
>   same carousel.

Comment: Now It works but  have a small issue <img src="banner" :alt="banner"> displays the image names in alt attribute but doesn't display the images in src attribute.

Comment: You should be using `<img :src="banner" :alt="banner">`

Comment: Yes I'm using like that but the results is the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot It works! =) I changed my paths from ../Assests/abc.png to src/Assests/abc.png. Now It works! May be Vue has a issue one recognizing paths. Anyways thanks a lot for your help. =D

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

> The data-ride="carousel" attribute tells Bootstrap to begin animating the carousel immediately when the page loads.

Vue hasn't mounted this component yet on page load. So you gotta initialize the slider only after it has mounted.

So you gotta remove `data-ride="carousel"`, and add `$('.carousel').carousel()` in the mounted hook (assuming that the jquery `$` is available as a global variable). Make sense ?

```
<template>
  <div class="">
    <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="carousel-item active" v-for="banner in banners">
      <img :src="`./assets/${banner}`" alt=""  class="img-fluid"   >

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      banners:["logo.png","index.png","Capture.png"]
    }
  },
  methods:{

  },
  mounted(){
      $('.carousel').carousel();
  }
}
</script>
```