# How can I make a bootstrap carousel with an API content?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

Good afternoon, I would like how can I add a dynamic carousel with Bootstrap 4?

Lemme explain, I'm using an API, I want to put an image and two texts:

I want "data.pic.src" to be my image, "data.headline" as my h3 and data.kicker as p.

Thank you =)

```js
function(item) {
    let response = item.news
        .map(data =>
            `<h3 class="line">${data.headline}</h3>
             <P class="title">${data.kicker}</p><br>
             <img src="${data.pic_src}" alt="oops" class="imagem">`
        )
        .join('')
    news.innerHTML = response
    })
}
```

```html
<div id="carouselSite" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="3"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="4"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner image">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img class="img-fluid d-block d-none d-md-block" src="" alt="imagem1">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
                  <p>Vivamus vestibulum, massa a porta pellentesque, neque nisi vestibulum ligula</p>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#carouselSite" class="carousel-control-prev" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#carouselSite" class="carousel-control-next" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Próximo</span>
      </a>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the error you are facing ?

Comment: Simply don't work, I know my function is correct, 'cause I tested, but for some reason, my content doesn't integrate in bootstrap, I'm thinking I'm need to do something in jquery for bootstrap, but I don't know jquery and I'm so confused

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49571307/vuejs-with-bootsrap-carousel-how-to-pass-images-to-the-carousel may help in some way

Comment: can you console log the response?

Also when is the function called ?

Comment: Ya, I can console.log the response, I've worked in this, I resolve some things, but I dunno how to resize the carousel and indicators, so my image isn't fit nicely.

Comment: When I resize my image with css, the right indicator stays out, my captions broke and a lot of things don't resize =(